# Understanding serialization proxies

Tags: java, serialization, proxy

I'm reading J.Bloch's Effective Java  and now I'm at the section about using serialization proxies. The question is not about the advantages of the whole process. I'm trying to understand one particular advantage of it.  Here's the advantage:

> There is another way in which the serialization pr oxy pattern is more
>   powerful than defensive copying. The serialization proxy pattern
>   allows the deserialized instance to have a different class from the
>   originally serialized instance.

As an example he provides the `EnumSet`'s serialization proxy which looks as follows (doc comments ommited):

```
private static class SerializationProxy <E extends Enum<E>>
    implements java.io.Serializable
{
    private final Class<E> elementType;
    private final Enum[] elements;

    SerializationProxy(EnumSet<E> set) {
        elementType = set.elementType;
        elements = set.toArray(ZERO_LENGTH_ENUM_ARRAY);
    }

    private Object readResolve() {
        EnumSet<E> result = EnumSet.noneOf(elementType);
        for (Enum e : elements)
            result.add((E)e);
        return result;
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 362491234563181265L;
}
```

I don't understand why can't we use just `readResolve` method to do that? We desirialize the `EnumSet` with `readObject` method correctly and the apply `readResolve()` to deserialized object. It's painful, but it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The serialization proxy pattern allows the deserialized instance to have a different class from the originally serialized instance.

This statement, and the code you've posted, are meaningless without the other side of the coin: the `writeReplace()` method of `EnumSet`. Unless that method returns a `SerializationProxy`, none of the code you've posted will ever be executed, and none of the commentary applies.

The purpose of `writeReplace()` and `readResolve()`, *as a pair*, is that the original class isn't serialized at all,but a proxy, via the write-replace mechanics, and that proxy resolves itself into an instance of the original class via the read-resolve mechanics.

Comment: You mean that if we define writeReplace, the method writeObject will not be executed? So, if we have complex invariants we should consider using proxies. But if we have a performance-sensitive piee of code it may probably be better to use `readResolve`/`writeReplace`, right?

Comment: I didn't state that 'the method `writeObject()` will not be executed', and I'm averse to having words placed into my mouth, but it's correct. If you can replace/resolve a complex object with a simpler object for serialization there might be some performance advantage, but it's difficult to envisage a scenario. The real purpose of replace/resolve to me seems to be architectural rather than performance-oriented.